# Cancel all request to activity recognition (android)

Tags: android, activity-recognition

I am running into a weird situation where I previous has created a pending intent for activity recognition updates

```
PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getService(mContext, getIntentID(), intent,
                PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
```

my getIntentID code is

```
private static int getIntentID(){
    if(intentID == 0)
        return intentID = (int)(System.currentTimeMillis());
    return intentID;
}
```

I did this because I wanted to be sure the id was unique everytime I stop and start my service.

However now when I am in my intentService reading the activities that are being sent I am pretty sure it is not my most recent pendingintent calling making the request. I believe it is from a previous one. However I don't know how to cancel it since I don't know the id from the previous one. 
1. Why don't I know the previous id? well when I cancelled the updates via the remove updates I did use my getIntentID which I thought was working correctly however when I stopped my app, started it again but didnt launch the update() code for the activity recognition, I noticed I was still getting activities, when I used the debugger.

Here is my update request

```
ActivityRecognition.ActivityRecognitionApi.requestActivityUpdates(getActivityRecognitionClient(),
            Utility.DETECTION_INTERVAL_TIME, pendingIntent())
```

Here is my remove code

```
 ActivityRecognition.ActivityRecognitionApi.removeActivityUpdates(getActivityRecognitionClient(),
            pendingIntent())
```

So my question is, is there a way to cancel all calls period to the activity recog. even if I dont know the pendingintent info?

Answer (score 0):

> So my question is, is there a way to cancel all calls period to the
>   activity recog.

If you refer the `API` of `ActivityRecognitionApi` it contains only two methods

https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/location/ActivityRecognitionApi

one for requesting updates

```
requestActivityUpdates(GoogleApiClient client, long detectionIntervalMillis, PendingIntent callbackIntent)
```

and

second one to remove updates

```
removeActivityUpdates(GoogleApiClient client, PendingIntent callbackIntent)
```

both methods need `PendingIntent`.

So obviously answer is **NO**.

Hope this will helps you.

Answer (score 0):

Okay there seems to be no way to cancel the pending intents to the activity recog. LIke Nag stated however what I ended up doing was changing the name of my intentservice class and using it instead and keeping track of the pending Id info. Now I don't have any request coming in from previous calls